# Removing nanoseconds in a datetime string

Tags: java, regex

#### What I'm trying to achieve...

I have dates in potentially 2 formats:

```
2013-07-03T14:30:38Z
2013-07-03T14:30:38.000000Z
```

I want to axe the `.00000` if it exists

I got this far, to remove everything after the '.'
time.replaceFirst(`"^(.*?)\\b\\..*$"`, "$1");

result: `2013-07-03T14:30:38`

Problem is, I still need the '`Z`' .. how can I keep the `Z` ?

#### I'm no Date Time expert...

so I'm not entirely sure if there will always be 6 0s (if the string contains the nanoseconds) or if there can be a variable number of 0s...

#### Java 8

I'm using java but didn't want to tag it as java since it's basically just pure regex

Comment: You have an iso8601 date strings in utc, you should be able to parse it using a datetime library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using java but didn't want to tag it as java since it's basically just pure regex

It's probably best to approach with `java.time`,
but since you insist:

```
time.replaceFirst( "\\.\\d*(Z)?$", "$1");
```

Answer (score 4):

## Strings != Date-Time

I should correct the terminology in the Question: You (apparently) have *strings* in a certain format, not "dates". **Do not confuse date-time values with their String representations.**

Just as "$12.34" is not a number, it is a string representation of a number with a certain format applied. That string can be parsed into a number.

This concept is the essence of the following code. We parse a string to instantiate a date-time object, then use that date-time object to generate a new string representation.

## java.time

Java 8 and later has a new [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built-in ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). You could use that for parsing a string as a date-time value, and then generating a new string representation in any format you desire. Here's some code if you want to explore this as an alternative to regex.

Both of your possible formats are nearly in [ISO 8601](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FISO_8601) format. Strictly speaking the standard expects only [millisecond](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMillisecond) resolution (3 decimal places) as far as I know, but the java.time framework extends that to [nanosecond](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNanosecond) (up to 9 decimal places).

The java.time framework uses ISO 8601 as its default when parsing and generating strings. So you need not specify a formatter pattern, and instead can use one of the several predefined formatters aimed at ISO 8601 standard formats.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time). You could assign a particular time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`, but not needed for this particular Question. This class can parse your input strings by default.

```
String input = "2013-07-03T14:30:38.123456789Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

After parsing we have an `instant` object in hand. From there we can effectively truncate the fractions of a second by calling the [`with`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) method to change the fractional second to zero. Technically speaking we are not *changing* the fractional seconds, as java.time uses [immutable objects](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FImmutable_object). A new object is created based on the values of the original.

```
Instant instantTruncated = instant.with( ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND , 0 );
```

Lastly we use the predefined formatter, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT). This formatter automatically suppresses the fractional zero from the generated string in groups of three digits where the value is zero. So `…7.12` prints as `…7.120`, `…7.1234` as `…7.123400`, and `…7.0` as `…7`. That last value is fits our needs.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
String output = formatter.format( instantTruncated );
```

The `toString` method on `Instant` uses the formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` by default. So technically we could shorten the code to just call `toString`. But I want to show explicitly how a formatter is involved.

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instant: " + instant );
System.out.println( "instantTruncated: " + instantTruncated );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run.

```
instant: 2013-07-03T14:30:38.123456789Z
instantTruncated: 2013-07-03T14:30:38Z
output: 2013-07-03T14:30:38Z
```

We can assign a time zone to that Instant to get a 'ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instantTuncated , zoneId);
```

Comment: great, thanks - good explanation.. I was having some problems for reasons other than I thought and I thought truncating the string would solve things - but it didn't, so I then implemented it with Instant and converted that to a LocalDateTime so it would work with the rest of my code... (which was what I originally tried to do but failed, but now it works).. but the regex examples help me learn regex, so that's good too )

Comment: @ycomp Usually, in most business apps, you should be using ZonedDateTime, not LocalDateTime. See my comment and my answer on [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32833896/642706).

Comment: ok,, thanks for the tip - I'll look into reworking my code with that - I'm very new to Java 8

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the `Z` back inside:

```
time.replaceFirst( "^(.*?)\\b\\..*$", "$1Z");
```

And alternative would be to capture everything until you encounter the period character (`.`):

```
time.replaceFirst( "^([^.]+).*(Z)$", "$1$2");
```