# Does Java 8's new Java Date Time API take care of DST?

Tags: java, datetime, datetimeoffset

I am thinking of using the new **java 8 Date Time API**. I googled a bit and found jodaTime as good choice for java but still kind of interested to see how this new API works.

I am storing all time in UTC values in my datastore and will be converting them to Local Time Zone specific value based on user's timezone. I can find many articles showing how to use new Java Date Time API. However I am not sure if the API will take care of DST changes ? 
Or do we have any better way of handling Date ?

I am just learning the new Date API , so thought of hearing your thoughts on handling the DateTime and displaying it on the basis of Users TimeZone.

Comment: In short: yes, DST is taken care of. Java 8 date-time API was created based on Joda time.

Comment: @Raja I'll correct your terms to prevent confusion… "Local" in date-time work means "for any locality", as in "Christmas starts at midnight December 25, 2015". Such a local date-time has no time zone. Indeed, it has no real meaning until you adjust it into a specific time zone. Midnight on the 25th comes earlier in Paris than in Montréal. So, in common business apps we rarely use "Local". You will be taking your stored date-time values from your database, working with them in your business logic in UTC generally, and adjusting to a `ZonedDateTime` only for presentation to a user.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It depends on which class you use:

- `Instant` is an instantaneous point on the global time-line (UTC), and is unrelated to time-zone.
- `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` have no concept of time-zone, but calling `now()` will of course give you your correct time.
- `OffsetDateTime` has a time-zone, but doesn't support Daylight Savings Time.
- `ZonedDateTime` has full time-zone support.

Converting between them usually requires a time-zone, so to answer your question:

Yes, Java 8 Date/Time **can** take care of DST, *if* you use it right.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that `OffsetDateTime` doesn't support DST, that's precisely what I needed, thanks!

Comment: `localDateTime.atZone( zoneId_LosAngeles );` <--- So localDateTime accepts zone; then why this answer says `LocalDateTime have no concept of time-zone`?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Because a `LocalDateTime` object has no concept of which time zone the date/time value it embeds belongs to. Just because the class supplies a *helper method* for converting the stored value to an object of a different type, doesn't mean that the object and its data knows anything about time zones. The `localDateTime.atZone(zoneId)` method is a *convenience method*, making it simpler to call than `ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, zoneId)`, which is exactly what it does for you, as you can see if you *look at the source code* of the method.

Answer (score 43):

[The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32834133/642706) by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) is spot-on correct.

## Example Code

Let's test it with some code. [DST in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States) & Canada expires this year at 02:00 on November 1, 2015.

Let‘s start with 1 AM in “local” date-time, meaning not tied to the timeline and ignoring the issue of time zones. Add an hour, and we get 2 AM. Makes sense.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of( 2015 , Month.NOVEMBER , 1 , 1 , 0 ); // 1 AM anywhere. Not tied the timeline nor to any time zone.
LocalDateTime localDateTimeOneHourLater = localDateTime.plusHours( 1 ); // 2 AM anywhere, in no particular time zone, ignoring DST.
```

Next we get specific, with a particular time zone. We take that 1 AM anywhere and put it into the time zone of `America/Los_Angeles` (west coast of United States).

```
ZoneId zoneId_LosAngeles = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
ZonedDateTime before = localDateTime.atZone( zoneId_LosAngeles ); // Assign a time zone, tying this vague date-time idea/generality to an actual moment on the time line.
```

Now add an hour, and see what we get. If DST is ignored, we’ll get 2 AM. If DST is respected, we’ll get 1 AM… when reaching 2 AM the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) jumps back to 1 AM but with a new offset-from-UTC. This is colloquially known as ["fall back"](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/spring-forward-fall-back.html) in the fall (autumn).

```
ZonedDateTime after = before.plusHours( 1 ); // 2 AM? Nope, 1 AM because DST Daylight Saving Time expires at 2 AM Nov 1, 2015.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "localDateTime : " + localDateTime );
System.out.println( "localDateTimeOneHourLater : " + localDateTimeOneHourLater );
System.out.println( "before : " + before );
System.out.println( "after : " + after );
```

When run, we get this output. Without a time zone, 1 AM + 1 hour = 2 AM. Remember these are "local" date-time values, **not UTC**. They represent only the vague idea of a date-time, not an actual moment on the timeline.

```
localDateTime : 2015-11-01T01:00
localDateTimeOneHourLater : 2015-11-01T02:00
```

But with time zones applied on the day DST expires, we get different results. Note how the time-of-day remains `01:00` but the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) changes from `-07:00` to `-08:00`.

```
before : 2015-11-01T01:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
after : 2015-11-01T01:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

Perhaps this would more clear and easier to verify if we adjust into UTC. We can do that simply by accessing the `before` and `after` objects as [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects. The [`System.out.println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) then implicitly calls the [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method.

```
System.out.println( "before.toInstant : " + before.toInstant() );
System.out.println( "after.toInstant : " + after.toInstant() );
```

When run.

```
before.toInstant : 2015-11-01T08:00:00Z
after.toInstant : 2015-11-01T09:00:00Z
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your contributions... I've noticed that you have quite a strong acumen with the Date/Time API's... :)

Comment: Great. I thought I'll have to do the daylight saving time conversion manually by adding an hour or using different timezone but java does it already for us. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Java API will take DST changes into account.

This tutorial explains quite well how to convert dates between timezones and how to choose the right class to represent a date:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html

You can also look at this class which represents the rules for each zone:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html

In particular, this method can tell you if a particular instant is in daylight savings:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings-java.time.Instant-

Comment: Thanks for reminding the value of Orcale docs :) Those links are more helpful to me.